# Ordinal addition is associative (prove with well-order definition).

Tags: set-theory, ordinals, well-orders

Let $\alpha, \beta$ be ordinals.

$$\alpha + \beta:= \operatorname{Ord}(A, \leq)$$

where $A= (\alpha \times \{0\}) \cup (\beta \times \{1\})$ and where $\leq$ is the lexicographic order on $A$.

I want to show (with this definition only!)

$$(\alpha+ \beta)+ \gamma = \alpha + (\beta + \gamma)$$

Maybe I can show that the left side and the right side are isomorphic well-orders? I can see why this intuitively holds: both sides are just a string with $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ after each other, but I can't make this formal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left hand side expands to $$(((\alpha\times\{0\})\cup(\beta\times\{1\}))\times\{0\})\cup(\gamma\times\{1\}),$$
while the right hand side expands to 
 $$(\alpha\times\{0\})\cup(((\beta\times\{0\})\cup(\gamma\times\{1\}))\times\{1\})$$
and an isomorphism from the former to the latter is given by the function $f$ defined by $f(a,0,0)=(a,0)$ for $a\in\alpha$, $f(b,1,0)=(b,0,1)$, for $b\in\beta$, and $f(g,1)=(g,1,1)$ for $g\in\gamma$.

Of course this is just all a messy way to say that in the left hand side you're putting a copy of $\gamma$ after a copy of "a copy of $\beta$ after a copy of $\alpha$", while on the right hand side you're putting a copy of "a copy of $\gamma$ after a copy of $\beta$" after a copy of $\alpha$ and there should obviously be no difference between the two.

Comment: The left hand side expands to: is this up to isomorphism? Because you just considered $(A, \leq)$ and not the unique ordinal associated with it?

Comment: @user745578 If you want to be *that* precise let $(A,\leq)$ be the order the left hand side expands to and let $(A',\leq)$ be the one the right hand side expands to. Let $\eta=\mathrm{Ord}(A,\leq)$ and let $\eta'=\mathrm{Ord}(A',\leq)$. I defined an isomorphism $f\colon A\to A'$, so to get an isomorphism $\eta\to\eta'$ you need to compose with isomorphisms $\eta\to A$ and $A'\to\eta'$ (which exist by definition of order type)

Comment: Thanks! I'll see that I can write this down neatly!

Comment: Using your idea I managed to write a full rigorous proof. Many thanks!

Comment: To be absolutely sure: would it be sufficient to prove that $\alpha+(\beta+\gamma)$ and $(\alpha+\beta)+\gamma$ are both order-isomorphic to $(\alpha \times \{0\})\cup(\beta\times \{1\}) \cup(\gamma \times \{2\})$ where the latter set has the lexicographic order? My proof uses this, so maybe you can tell if this is a good way to proceed and if this even is true?

Comment: Sure, it is true and that works, even though it's not necessary, since you can show directly an isomorphism between the two sets in my answer @user745578